# If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, grafana

I want to run grafana behind nginx. I followed [this instruction](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/). The only problem I have right now is whenever I try to edit a panel, I will see this error message below. It disappears in a few seconds. The grafana.ini looks like

```
domain=localhost
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana/
serve_from_sub_path = true
```

The scrubbed nginx.conf looks like

```
server_name 1.2.3.4 # my public id address
location /grafana/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
```

I don't really experience any issue other than the annoying error message every time I want to edit a panel. When I used SSH to bind port 3000 to my computer `ssh -L 3000:localhost:3000 my_id@1.2.3.4`, everything worked just fine. Any suggestions on how to fix the problem?

[image: Grafana error message]